# Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications IDE AutoCorrects my Date Datatype into 12 hour time

Tags: excel, vba

My computer runs on 24 hour time, the Excel sheet I am working on runs in 24 hour time. Whenever I type a time in the VBA IDE it switches the time to 12 hour time!

Example:

If I type

```
TimeExample = #22:00#
```

It is auto corrected to

```
TimeExample = #10:00:00 PM#
```

I have tried different data types, format functions, Very frustrated..

Comment: _Whenever I type a time in the VBA IDE it switches the time to 12 hour time_ << can you describe in detail how this happens? An example with code will help.

Comment: Is that wrong?  #6:00# is presumably same as 6AM ?   Maybe use `TimeSerial()` if you want things to remain as-typed.

Comment: This is by design. Accept the behaviour - _resistance is futile_.

Comment: `#22:00#` is the same as `#10:00:00 PM#` so I see no issue with that. This is converted into a `date` or `double` anyway. Since times are a fraction of a day and therefore stored as `double`. So `1` is a full day and `10:00:00 PM` therefore is stored as `0,916666666` which is `91,66 %` of `1 day`. • There is nothing wrong with Excel doing that. Everting is correct, I don't see why you think this is an problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSerial`:

```
TimeExample = TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)
```